# Control default contact list and messages app

Tags: android

Is there a way I can control what contact list and messages show? I want to make an app that if enabled will hide certain contacts or messages from certain people. I am not sure of this is doable
Please let me know if this can be done programmatically. Please note that I am referring to the default contact/messages APP that comes with android and I want to be able to control what it shows from my app

Thank you

Comment: Since both of them use contentprovider you can surely delete and insert data to the database. So I think the only way is to delete the entries from database when it is not visible and to re insert it when it should be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please note that I am referring to the default contact/messages APP that comes with android and I want to be able to control what it shows from my app

Fortunately, this is not possible, except by modifying the actual data, as noted in a comment on your question. You cannot hack into other apps like some script kiddie.

Note that, due to synchronization, deleting contacts may wind up deleting them from an upstream data source. The user may not appreciate this.

You are welcome to build your own contact app that maintains its own filtered list of contacts.

Comment: CommonsWare, thank you, you have always been helpful. The thing is that I am trying to do a user profile. Sortof like what the recent feature in the newest android version. The user can unlock the phone with a certain code and then can see specific contacts/messages. Is this doable?

Comment: @Snake: Not without building your own custom version of Android,  building your own "contacts/messages" apps, or doing really risky things with the data on the device (e.g., delete stuff and later restore it).